# hibernate grails ordering changes the number of results

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain Location that has a child Tour.
If I order by the tour, the amount of results changes

```
 Location.withCriteria{
         tour{
               order('date')
         }
 }//will gives me fewer results than

 Location.withCriteria{
         order('name')
 }
```

I've tried various ways of defining the relationship, using belongsTo, hasOne, ect, but haven't landed anything that gives the same number of results.

Comment: You may want to include more about your domain classes to help answer this question. Is it possible for a Location to exist without a Tour? If so that would explain why you get less results (e.g. only ones with Tours) in the first query.

Comment: I had set the fetchMode to use Hibernate's outer join, but it looks like you are right- the order clause causes an inner join to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Using "totalCount" to get the record number for pagination may cause a discrepancy.

```
records.totalCount
```

This fires another auto-generated sql query that may use inner join by default. If the original criteria uses [hibernate's fetchMode.JOIN, it will use outer join by default](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/FetchMode.html). This could cause a difference you weren't expecting..

A workaround is to create your own count query.